# how can we avoid allocation done by Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi?

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, interop

My wrapper from managed to unmanaged is handling a lot of data and this function Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi would call new for each of them, which is a big hit for me. So my question is:

Can I allocate a chunk of unmanaged memory and use it to convert the  managed data types to unmanaged by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all of the characters in the `System::String` are in the ASCII range, the most basic implementation would be something like:

```
void ConvertAndCopy(System::String^ ms, char* us)
{
    for (int i(0); i < ms->Length; ++i)
        us[i] = static_cast<char>(ms[i]);

    us[ms->Length] = '\0';
}

// usage example:
System::String^ ms = "Hello world";
char us[12] = "";

ConvertAndCopy(ms, us);
```

Note that this performs no bounds-checking on the destination array and does not do any character set conversion.

Whether this performs any better than `StringToHGlobalAnsi` or whether any performance gains are worth the significant increase in complexity (namely, managing your own memory and handling character set conversions), I have no idea.

Comment: More general (handles non-ASCII): `PtrToStringChars`, `pin_ptr`, and `WideCharToMultiByte`

Answer (score -1):

Give this a shot.

```
char *poutputString = (char *)(void *)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(inputString);
// do something with poutputString here
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(poutputString);
```

This is the only way I've seen it used. Can you provide a code snippet of the way it's being used in your case?

Comment: this "Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi" does allocate memory inside, that is the problem.

Comment: Ah, okay. He was referring to a guy calling new, so I misinterpreted.

Comment: WTF is `(char*)(void*)`? fairly epic fail.